# 'echo $var' vs 'echo($var)'

Tags: php, echo

My code editor has a build in snippet for echo that looks like this:

```
echo($var);
```

All the snippets that I browse on the internet are formated without parentheses. Like this:

```
echo $var;
```

What is the difference? Which one is correct or considered as a better practice?

Comment: echo is not really a function. using brackets is pretty unneccessary. but you can use brackets for calculations like this: `echo "hello ". (4+5);`
you can also use commas to seperate strings: `echo "hello ", "my ", "friend`

Answer (score 3):

[echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you are not required to use parentheses with it. echo (unlike some other language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot always be used in the context of a function. Additionally, if you want to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters must not be enclosed within parentheses.

Going through the documentation , you can notice, that is not a problem, but really unnecessary and  I believe your code editor have some setting, you may like to change to get it normal .